# Why can't scipy.optimize.curve_fit fit my data using a numpy.sinc function?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I can't use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to fit data generated with numpy.sinc.  Even when I do (or at least I think I do) the exact same thing as in the scipy documentation. Here is my simple try:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xdata = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = 100*np.sinc(xdata - 3) + 1
y_noise = np.random.normal(3, 2, 200)
ydata = y + y_noise

def func(x, a, h, k):
    return(a*np.sinc(x - h) + k)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt))
plt.show()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) with an initial guess using `p0=[...]`

For example:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xdata = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
y = 100*np.sinc(xdata - 3) + 1
y_noise = np.random.normal(3, 2, 200)
ydata = y + y_noise

def func(x, a, h, k):
    return(a*np.sinc(x - h) + k)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=[100, 1, 1])

plt.plot(xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What method did you use to determine the initial parameter estimates that you provide in your example?

Comment: @JamesPhillips None whatsoever ;-) which is why Warren's answer is much better than mine..

Answer (score 3):

For many functions, it is essential that you give `curve_fit` a "pretty good" initial guess for the parameters.  Without it, the optimization routine finds a local minimum of its objective function that is actually a bad fit.

In your case, I got a nice fit by using:

```
k = ydata.argmax()
p0 = [ydata[k], xdata[k], ydata.mean()]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata, p0=p0)
```

Here's the plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Say, that is a really snazzy way to find initial parameter estimates for this problem - my complements on the excellent results.